# Enum - output is printed for all the parameters, expecting only for one

Tags: java, enums

When I run the below code I am expecting it to print the Mango price only, but output is for all the enum members.
Please can some one explain it?

```
enum fruit
{
    apple(100), mango(400), banana(40), cherry(2000);

    fruit(int Price) //constructor
    {
        this.Price=Price;
        System.out.println(Price);
    }

    int Price;

    public int getPrice()
    {
        return Price;
    }
}

public class A

{
    fruit getValue;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A o = new A();
        o.getValue=fruit.mango;
        //System.out.println("Mango Price is "+o.getValue.getPrice());
    }
}
```

O/P:

100
400
40
2000

Answer (score 4):

An `enum` is a compile time constant, when the `enum` class is loaded each of the *values* is *instantiated* **once** (at `apple(100), mango(400), banana(40), cherry(2000);`). In the context of `fruit`, it's **very** similar to `fruit` references like

```
// At the byte-code they look something like
private fruit apple = new fruit(100);
private fruit mango = new fruit(400);
private fruit banana = new fruit(40);
private fruit cherry = new fruit(2000);
```

Also,please respect Java variable naming conventions. Class names start with a capital letter, and `enum`(s) are usually ALLCAPS. Next,

```
o.getValue=fruit.mango;
```

Is a **terrible** field name. Please prefer a setter.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are Using `fruit(int Price) ;` Constructor so it salways call Four Values. because values is instantiated one time for `apple(100), mango(400), banana(40), cherry(2000);`

- Java Enum can have `Constructor` to pass data while creating `Enum` constants.

  ```
  apple(100), mango(400), banana(40), cherry(2000);
  fruit(int Price) //constructor Load all values or instantiated once
  {
  this.Price=Price;
  System.out.println(Price);
  }
  ```